# Truncate table in H2Database with DB2 syntax

Tags: hibernate, junit, db2, h2, truncate

I am trying to test my DB2 queries with h2database, but I am facing problems when trying to truncate a table.

Here is my query: `TRUNCATE TABLE SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME IMMEDIATE`

The error:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "TRUNCATE TABLE TOPACC.STREAM_FORECAST IMMEDIATE[*]"; SQL statement:
TRUNCATE TABLE TOPACC.STREAM_FORECAST IMMEDIATE [42000-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:451)
```

My config:

```
private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
    properties.put("hibernate.default_schema", "SCHEMA_NAME");
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.h2.Driver");
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.username", "NAME");
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.password", "");
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=DB2;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS SCHEMA_NAME");
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");

    return properties;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

H2 compatibility modes do not provide full support for engine spefic SQL syntax. In this particular case DB2 compatibility mode does not support `IMMEDIATE` option for `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement.

Details of compatibility modes can be found from [H2 documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility)